# How to stop cURL from formatting URL string in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to parse an API request with cURL, however I've just discovered (with `curl_getinfo`) after hours of debugging that my URL is being formatted - specifically special characters such as `/` and `?`.

This is being caused by the fact that I am causing `urlencode($apiQuery)` which formats the url to remove whitespaces, but incidentally causes issues for the entire url.

I am trying to write this in PHP, and have set my cURL request as follows:

```php
$apiQuery = 'api.server.com/v0/Accounts/USER/INSTRUMENT?channels=all&start=2022-10-30 21:00:00';

$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($apiQuery));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $c , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $c , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $c , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt( $c , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50000); // 50 sec

$resultA = curl_exec($c);

print_r(curl_getinfo($c));
```

where `$resultA` returns nothing, and `curl_getinfo($c)` returns:

```
Array
(
    [url] => HTTP://api.server.com%2Fv0%2FAccounts%2FUSER%2FINSTRUMENT%3Fchannels%3Dall%26start%3D2022-10-30+21%3A00%3A00/
    [content_type] =>
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] =>
    [primary_ip] =>
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] =>
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to split the $apiQuery string:

```
$apiQuery = 'http://api.server.com/v0/Accounts';

$apiQuery .= '/' . urlencode($user);
$apiQuery .= '/' . urlencode($instrument);
$apiQuery .= '?';

$apiQuery .= http_build_query([
    'channels' => 'all',
    'start' => '2022-10-30 21:00:00',
]);
```

`http_build_query` also url escapes your params.